# Stack Overflow: Consolidate the tags [getter-setter], [getters-setters]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

The tags [getters-setters] [getter-setter] are indistinguishable and one of them should go away.

Please note: [getter-setter] has only 9 questions and [getters-setters] has 135 questions. Contrary to these numbers I propose to merge the plural form into the singular form since that corresponds with the actual usage of term.

An nearly extreme form can be [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388837/why-getter-setter-if-return-value-is-mutable) where together with the [getter(s)] and [setter(s)] tags the tag limit is exceeded.